# MATLAB using 2D Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, image-processing

i want to use a 2D array to store all the values of img1, img2 and the compared vlaue of img1 and img2, 
I want to achive the algorithm likes:

```
% read in the images from a folder one by one:
    somefolder = 'folder';
    filelist = dir([somefolder '/*.jpg']);
    s=numel(filelist);
    C = cell(length(filelist), 1);
    for k=1:s
       C{k}=imread([somefolder filelist(k).name]); 
    end
%choose any of the two images to compare
    for t=1:(s-1)
        for r=(t+1):s
           img1=C{r};
           img2=C{t};
           ssim_value[num][1]=img1;   % first img
           ssim_value[num][2]=img2;   % second img
           ssim_value[num][3]=mssim;  % ssim value of these two images

        end 
    end
```

So, there is error about using the 2D array (ssim_value) that I used, what is the correct way of initialization it, and how to achieve the purpose that save the values that I want to store.

Could someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a python background? Give `ssim_value` a try without the square brackets. Try something like: `ssim_value{num,1}`

Comment: Thanks, I tried your method, it may works, I need to load the whole folder images to see how, tks.

Comment: Use `fullfile` command to create strings for file/folder names: `fullfile( somefolder, '*.jpg' )` is better than `[somefolder '/*.jpg']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that "num" is a number that you will supply, like 5 or something.  You cannot mix types in arrays as you do in Python.  Also, as @Schorsch pointed out, you use parenthesis to index arrays in Matlab.

The two-dimensional array you are trying to form needs to be a 2-D cell array.  For example:

```
a = {{"a",3},{"two",[1,2,3]};
```

In this case, a{1,2} = 3, and a{2,1} = "two".

You may not know in advance how many files are in the directory, so pre-initializing the cell array may not be possible in advance.  In any case, Matlab arrays only need to be pre-initialized for performance reasons, and you can easily find information on initializing arrays in Matlab.

In light of this, I'm pretty sure what you are trying to accomplish is:

```
%choose any of the two images to compare
    ssim_value = {};
    for t=1:(s-1)
        for r=(t+1):s
           img1=C{r};
           img2=C{t};
           ssim_value{num,1}=img1;   % first img
           ssim_value{num,2}=img2;   % second img
           ssim_value{num,3}=mssim;  % ssim value of these two images

        end 
    end
```